# Output for an Excel Cell with Reference to another Cell

Tags: excel, reference, cell

help needed! couldnt find much information online. Either my question was too confusing or I wasn't clear enough!

Anyway, would love some help on the following.

I have a column of calls and a typical cell contains values separated by commas as such,

"value A, value B, value C"

i have another column which I only need certain value of this cell. Let's say i only need Value A.

How should i do this? Is there a formula i could use?

Answer (score 0):

Use this formula to achieve that.

```
=LEFT(A1,SEARCH(",",A1,1)-1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

How to do this is explained on numerous places on the internet, like [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Split-text-among-columns-by-using-functions-f836abfc-9d4b-4586-acee-a042b469b30f).

In your case you would have something like this in row 2:

- A2: `Value A, Value B, Value C`
- B2: `=SEARCH(",",A2)`
- C2: `=TRIM(LEFT(A2, B2-1))`
- D2: `=SEARCH(",",A2,B2+1)`
- E2: `=TRIM(MID(A2,B2+1,D2-B2-1))`
- F2: `=TRIM(MID(A2,D2+1,9999))`

You then get these values:

```
|             A             | B |    C    |  D |    E    |    F    |
+---------------------------+---+---------+----+---------+---------+
| Value A, Value B, Value C | 8 | Value A | 17 | Value B | Value C |
```

The values in column B and D are intermediate values, i.e. the positions of the commas, so you could just hide those columns.

### Generalising this Solution

You could extend the above idea to allow for more commas in the original string, to get something like in this image:

[image]

You can view that document via [Google Docs](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yPZmrOARM9F2edQs1KrGS2h4r85r9Z1etyoeEL4SOAE/edit?usp=sharing)

In the pictured set-up, cells in the *N* column have a literal zero (no formula): this helps making the formulas in the yellow area uniform. In fact, with this solution you only have 2 kinds of formulas:

In cell *O2* the following formula is used:

```
=IFERROR(SEARCH(",",$A2&",",N2+1), N2+1)
```

The error checking (`IFERROR`) is there to deal with words (in column *A*) that have fewer commas than expected. The `$` in `$A2` makes it possible to copy this cell to the rest of the yellow area without change.

In cell *B2* the following formula is used:

```
=TRIM(MID($A2,N2+1,O2-N2-1))
```

It references the values in *N2* and *O2*, so be sure to have those defined first. Again, you can copy this cell to the rest of the orange area without change.

When you need support for even more commas in the original text, do the following:

1. Extend the yellow area to the right, copying the cells and adding the required extra number of columns
2. Insert before the column with the zeroes (*N*) the same number of extra columns, and copy the orange cells into them.

When all is like you want it, you can hide the columns on the right side, so you just have the split words (in the orange area) visible.